# Building a database of time series using a loop

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I there's a lot on here about merging databases but I'm struggling with my problem.

I'm looking to create a database of racing results. I get all my data from csv files, there's csv files for the win market, and the place market, and 1 for each, on each day. So every date has 2 csv files, a win and a place.

I've attempted to start creating this data base by joining the last 2 days data together. Which has worked nicely so far.

```
import pandas as pd

win_1 = pd.read_csv('dwbfpricesukwin17092018.csv')
win_2 = pd.read_csv('dwbfpricesukwin16092018.csv')
place_1 = pd.read_csv('dwbfpricesukplace17092018.csv')
place_2 = pd.read_csv('dwbfpricesukplace16092018.csv')

win_data = win_1.append(win_2)
place_data = place_1.append(place_2)

place_data.rename(columns={'WIN_LOSE': 'WIN_LOSE_PLC', 'BSP': 'BSP_PLC'}, inplace=True)

total_data = win_data.merge(place_data[['WIN_LOSE_PLC', 'BSP_PLC', 'SELECTION_NAME']], on='SELECTION_NAME', how='outer')

total_data[['EVENT_DT', 'SELECTION_NAME', 'WIN_LOSE', 'BSP', 'WIN_LOSE_PLC', 'BSP_PLC']].to_csv('data.csv')
```

However I want to create a data base for the whole year.

I was thinking of creating two variables, start and end date and looping thru them, getting the loop to change the date in the csv file. But I kind of don't really know where to start.

```
start_date = '01012018'
end_date = '17092018'
```

How can I get the loop to know those two numbers are dates, and to go thru them 1 day at a time?

Also am I right to use .append here? I wanted to use join or merge but it would just create new columns instead of sending the new data to the bottom of the data base.

I hope I've explained myself enough, thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `Pandas.date_range` with list comprehension.

Something like this:

```
win_template = 'dwbfpricesukwin{}.csv'
place_template = 'dwbfpricesukwin{}.csv'

start_date = '2018-01-01'
end_date = '2018-09-17'
dates = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date, freq='D')

win_files = [win_template.format(x.strftime('%d%m%Y')) for x in dates]
place_files = [place_template.format(x.strftime('%d%m%Y')) for x in dates]
```

Then continuing with list comprehensions, create your DataFrames using `Pandas.concat`:

```
df_win = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(win) for win in win_files])
df_place = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(place) for place in place_files])
```

Comment: Hi mate, thanks so much for your help, that's basically exactly what I'm after, and your answer makes total sense to me. However for some reason I am receiving this error: 'FileNotFoundError: File b'dwbfpricesukwin{}.csv' does not exist'. The files are in the same directory as my code file. And worked fine before I put the {} in, which I know is needed for the code to edit the file name. Thanks again in advance for any help

Comment: @topbantz can you post the exact code you're using? Looks like the filepath isn't being formatted correctly. Also, not sure by it's being passed as bytes type..?

Comment: import pandas as pd

win_template = pd.read_csv('dwbfpricesukwin{}.csv')
place_template = pd.read_csv('dwbfpricesukplace{}.csv')

start_date = '16092018'
end_date = '18092018'
dates = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date, freq='D')

win_data = [win_template.format(x.strftime('%d%m%Y')) for x in dates]
place_data = [place_template.format(x.strftime('%d%m%Y')) for x in dates]

df_win = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(win) for win in win_data])
df_place = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(place) for place in place_data])

Comment: How does it know to format the date as 18092018 for example, and not 180918, if we use %d%m%Y in the code?

Comment: The problem is your assignment of `win_template` and `place_template`... they should be strings, not DataFrames. just set them to `win_template = 'dwbfpricesukwin{}.csv'` and `place_template = 'dwbfpricesukplace{}.csv'
`

Comment: Ah sorry that's my fault, I didn't copy your code I just altered mine, I'm now getting ValueError: could not convert string to Timestamp , supposedly coming from this line: dates = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date, freq='D')

sorry for being a pain

Comment: Also  with date formatting, `%Y` is year as 4 digits, whereas `%y` will be 2 digits

Comment: try passing `start_date = '2018-01-01'` and `end_date = '2018-09-17'`

Comment: Ahhhh I see yeah so I don't have to put the correct format in the start/end_date cos we format it correctly later on, yes that's worked. Thanks so much for your help mate, legend.

Comment: @topbantz happy to help bud